# Checking for all possible errors in a promise based login function

Tags: javascript, optimization, coding-style

I have created a function that takes user credentials and checks if the can log in a user.
My function returns a promise that should be resolved when the correct credentials were given, or else rejected.

```
login: function(credentials){
            var dfd = $q.defer();

            if(!credentials) dfd.reject('No user credentials given');
            else if(!credentials.name || !credentials.name.length) dfd.reject('No username given');
            else if(!credentials.password || !credentials.password.length) dfd.reject('No password given');
            else if(!self.database.hasOwnProperty(credentials.name)) dfd.reject('Unknown user');

            else if(credentials.password == self.database[credentials.name].password){                
                dfd.resolve(true);
            }

            else{
                dfd.reject('Wrong password');
            }

            return dfd.promise;
        },
```

While my code works, i find it difficult to read and chaotic.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can i write this in a cleaner way?
2. Can i stop my function from executing the rest of the code, when, for example, no name was entered?

edit:

A new approach:

```
    login: function(credentials){

        var dfd = $q.defer();
        var self = this;

        if(!credentials){

            dfd.reject('No user credentials given');

        } else if(!credentials.name || !credentials.name.length){

            dfd.reject('No username given');

        } else if(!credentials.password || !credentials.password.length){

            dfd.reject('No password given');

        } else if(!self.database.hasOwnProperty(credentials.name)){

            dfd.reject('Unknown user');

        } else if(credentials.password == self.database[credentials.name].password){

            self.name = sessionStorage.name = credentials.name;
            self.email = sessionStorage.email = self.database[credentials.name].email;

            if(credentials.remember){
                localStorage.name = credentials.name;
                localStorage.email = self.database[credentials.name].email;
            }

            dfd.resolve(true);

        } else{

            dfd.reject('Wrong password');
        }

        return dfd.promise;
```

Comment: Personally I find the code needlessly difficult to read because a) the style is not consistent and b) you are not using braces and newlines everywhere.

Comment: @Jon,
Thank you. I have added another approach, would you say that this one is better?

Comment: I think it's better, but personally I would move the "if everything is OK" part outside the conditional. Check for failure conditions with if/else, then a separate if (!dfd.isRejected()) and you move the code in there. To me that's better separation of logic. Also, this question should probably be moved to Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Switch statement for a cleaner code.
2. "return" will force to exit from the function without executing the rest of code

Comment: Return would also prevent my function from returning my promise

Comment: @user2422960: Obviously you would return the promise in *all* occurrences of `return`. But you don't even need to do that because `if`/`else if` will always evaluate just a single branch body.

Comment: If you need to always return dfd.promise you can simply do something like this:

if(!credentials) dfd.reject('No user credentials given'); return dfd.promise;